# Calculating area under linear line

Tags: linear-algebra, integration

I am writing some software to calculate the area under a linear line in order to estimate the distance traveled. In order to simplify my calculation (and reduce computation time in my software) I wanted to know if the area under a linear curve can be calculated by simply converting the linear line into a horizontal line whos y value is the average speed between t1 and t2 instead.

To better illustrate what i mean i have included curve as well as an example of the converted rectangle.

[Example waveform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOPlo.png)

Comment: Assuming the function to be integrated is constant over that interval and all you are asking for is the area, yes this follows from elementary geometry.  Alternatively, you could approach this via integral calculus directly and avoid the need for such simplifications.

Comment: Thank you :) yes it is constant over a set interval. This should really help improve my computation speed!

Comment: Think of it as calculating the area of a trapezoid, so the average works!